# Simple and customizable contact form with option to send copy to submitter

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7, contact

I'm looking for a simple contact form that allows easy styling on the fields and most important includes a checkbox to send a copy of the message to the submitter (e.g  ☑ send copy to myself)

Does anybody knows anyone? I've been playing with Contact Form 7, but couldn't find a way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a plugin or a way to write the code?

Comment: If there is already a plugin that can handle it, then a plugin would be great. If someone already did this by modifying the Contact Form 7 plugin and has the snippet, that's perfect too.

Comment: Not sure if plugin recommendations have been discouraged but Gravity Forms is a fantastic plugin for any kind of contact form and has options for send a copy to submitter by default.  It's well worth the cost.

Comment: Thanks but forgot to mention that needs to be free and Gravity Forms is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a copy of the mail to the sender using Contact Form 7. If you require their email use the second mail option and then put the name tag exp: [example-tag] that you used in creating the form in the receiver part of the mail.

Here are some screen shots below to illustrate what i mean:

Here is your basic Contact Form 7 form. You will notice that there is a input for email that i have.  `[email* your-email]`
[image: Here is your basic form]

Next here is the email that you will receive. With the tag `[your-email]`
[image: Here is the email that you will recieve]

Now you want to send a secondary email to the submitter. Right below the first set of mail you have a check box that says Mail2. Check it.

You will get this:
[image: second mail]

In the To: area put in the tag `[your-email` or whatever you used to call your email input box.

It will now send a message to both you and a mail to your submitter. Don't forget to put a message in the box next to the other input fields and the other tags as well.

Comment: I'm aware of this Mail 2 feature but I want the submitter to decide if they want to get a copy of the email by checking a checkbox. Is that possible?

Comment: I have not tried it that way but I don't see a reason as to why it can't be done.

Comment: I can see that CF7 has this action hook: [`do_action_ref_array( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', array( &$this ) );`](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/contact-form-7/tags/3.3.1/includes/classes.php). A search for the [hook name](https://www.google.com/search?q=wpcf7_before_send_mail&oq=wpcf7_before_send_mail&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) shows many results, but I'll leave the indepth research for you guys :)